# Find the best grade with Classes in C++

Tags: c++

This is the code I have to make 3 students and below i have the logic to find the best grade, in this case `nota_mesatare` is the best value that it should be.

But the problem this logic is not dyanmic, and I don't know how to do it it dinamicly.

So I can get rid of those ifs

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Studenti{
    private:
        string name;
        string fakulteti;
        
    public: 
        double nota_mesatare;
        
    Studenti(string n, string f, double mes){
        name = n;
        fakulteti = f;
        nota_mesatare = mes;
    }
};

int main() {
    
    Studenti one("Benjamin", "UNT", 5.5);
    Studenti two("Amar", "UNT", 2.6);
    Studenti thre("Sheat", "UNT", 5.3);
    
    
    double best;
    
    if(one.nota_mesatare > two.nota_mesatare && 
       one.nota_mesatare > thre.nota_mesatare){
        best = one.nota_mesatare;
    }
    
    else if(two.nota_mesatare > one.nota_mesatare && 
       two.nota_mesatare > thre.nota_mesatare){
        best = two.nota_mesatare;
    }
    
    else best = thre.nota_mesatare;;

    
    cout << "Nota mesatare me e mira eshte: " << best;
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "logic is not dynamic"? Please describe what the endresult should be

Comment: If you mean handling an arbitrary number of Students, you should use a `vector` to store them. Assume the first has the highest grade, then look for another student that has a better grade.

Comment: General suggestion: When you have sequentially named or numbered variables, you code will almost certainly be easier to write with an array or other container. With an array you can have a for loop that iterates the whole array, updating `best` every time it finds a higher grade.

Comment: Generic programming advice (1): English is the *lingua franca* of programming, and the language all those keywords and library functions are in. Get into the habit of using English identifiers in your code as well, because sooner or later someone *not* sharing your native language will read your code (as is the case here). English identifiers are just all-around better at documenting what it is you're doing. (And I say this as a non-native English speaker myself.)

Comment: Generic programming advice (2): Always be verbose. Put parenthesis even where they are optional (like in your compound conditionals). Always put braces even where they are optional (like your `else` branch). Use e.g. `std::string` and `std::cout` instead of `using namespace std;`. Personally I would also add a padding space inside of parenthesis, but I know that one's a matter of taste. You will find that all those make your code clearer, less ambiguous, and you will avoid a couple of nasty bugs down the road.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only in the largest grade, you can use `std::max` in the `algorithm` header with the grades from your objects:

```
Studenti one("Benjamin", "UNT", 5.5);
Studenti two("Amar", "UNT", 2.6);
Studenti thre("Sheat", "UNT", 5.3);
    
    
double best = std::max(std::max(one.nota_mesatare, two.nota_mesatare), thre.nota_mesatare);
```

A more elegant and Object Oriented way is to define a comparison rule between two objects of type `Studenti`. You can do that by overloading the less operator (<) like this:

```
bool operator<(const Studenti & otherStudent) const {
    return nota_mesatare < otherStudent.nota_mesatare;
}
```

That operator says that two students will be sorted by their grade, and the code should go inside your class, in the public section. Then, if you know you have exactly three students, you can use the same `std::max` in the `algorithm` header to find the max grade. `std::max` takes two objects of the same type and returns the larger one.

```
Studenti one("Benjamin", "UNT", 5.5);
Studenti two("Amar", "UNT", 2.6);
Studenti thre("Sheat", "UNT", 5.3);
    
    
double best = std::max(std::max(one, two), thre).nota_mesatare;
```

If you have multiple students, you can use `std::max_element` in header `algorithm` to get an iterator to the largest element (in your case, the student with the highest grade). Having multiple students, means you need to place them in some sort of a list container, like a regular array or a smarter `std::vector<Studenti>`.